# How to run Skaffold with a bootstrapped .NET Core API Docker project?

Tags: .net, kubernetes, yaml, skaffold

I'm looking into using Skaffold.dev to improve my development experience with Kubernetes.

I've created a default .NET API project and it's autogenerated my docker file:

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TestMicro/TestMicro.csproj", "TestMicro/"]
RUN dotnet restore "TestMicro/TestMicro.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TestMicro"
RUN dotnet build "TestMicro.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TestMicro.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TestMicro.dll"]
```

I have created a Kubernetes manifest and all is running ok using `kubectl apply`.

After installing skaffold, I ran `skaffold init` and it autogenerated this

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta8
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: microservices-investigation
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: testmicro
    context: src\Microservices\TestMicro
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
    - k8s/TestMicro.yaml
```

However, when I run `skaffold run` I get the following:

```
$ skaffold run
Generating tags...
 - testmicro -> testmicro:bd61fc5-dirty
Checking cache...
 - testmicro: Error checking cache.
failed to build: getting hash for artifact "testmicro": getting dependencies for "testmicro": file pattern [TestMicro/TestMicro.csproj] must match at least one file
```

I think this is because, when I run `docker build` from the CLI, I have to run `docker build -f Dockerfile ..` [see why here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/containers/container-build?view=vs-2019#docker-build).

I just can't figure out how to translate this into skaffold's yaml file. Any ideas?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Skaffold, the artifact `context` (sometimes called the *workspace*) is the working directory when building the artifact.  For Docker-based artifacts (the default artifact type), the artifact context is the root of the Docker build context and the `Dockerfile` in the root of the artifact's context.  You can specify an alternative Dockerfile location but it must live within the artifact context.

Normally `skaffold init` will create a `skaffold.yaml` where the artifact context is the directory containing a `Dockerfile`.  So if I understand your situation, I think you normally run your `docker build -f Dockerfile ..` in `src/Microservices/TestMicro`. So you should be able to also run your `docker build` via:

```
C:> cd ...\src\Microservices
C:> docker build -f TestMicro\Dockerfile .`
```

So you need to change your artifact definition to the following:

```
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: testmicro
    context: src/Microservices
    docker:
      dockerfile: TestMicro/Dockerfile
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks. Interestingly, the init script added the slashes the wrong way - `src\Microservices\TestMicro` (I guess because I'm on Windoze). Copying your code exactly worked, but it doesn't with the slashes reversed. This may be a bug with skaffold init...